# Loopback's skip and limit filter not working together with where filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I'm developing my REST API using Loopback framework. I'm using the concept of pagination in my application and for that i use the skip and limit filter as Loopback's documentation suggest.

But when I use these filters together with the where filter, I'm not getting the expected result.

This is my code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var filter = {
      where: {feedId: req.query.id},
      limit : req.query.limit,
      skip : req.query.skip
  };

  var Feeds = server.models.feeds;
  Feeds.find(filter, function(err, feeds) {
      res.send(feeds);
  });
});
```

Both where and limit filters are working perfect when we use it alone.
Anyone have any ideas? How can I make it work?

Comment: Your code looks OK. Aren't you by any chance skipping more items then you have in DB? Try with `skip: 0` to be sure.

Comment: Is it Mongoose? please specify it.

Comment: @Molda, i dont think so. Have more items in db and im sure im trying the skip filter with 0.

Comment: @Michelem , yea im using the mongoDb. I think the connector is more stable , so,  it doesn't matter which db im using behind since it is a loopback standard.

Comment: Are you sure you want to find a feed with an id and use `limit` and `skip` together? You might be trying to find all fields when id is not present and in that case, you can modify filter accordingly.